# Difficulty Using JavaScript Iterators

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator

Hope you're having a great day.  I'm having trouble getting the expected outcome with my iterators.  I looked on the MDN docs about iterators and I feel as though I understand how to use them but I may be mistaken as I am very new to coding.

Below is my code:

```
    let story =
  'Last weekend, I took literally the most beautiful bike ride of my life. The route is called "The 9W to Nyack" and it actually stretches all the way from Riverside Park in Manhattan to South Nyack, New Jersey. It\'s really an adventure from beginning to end! It is a 48 mile loop and it basically took me an entire day. I stopped at Riverbank State Park to take some extremely artsy photos. It was a short stop, though, because I had a really long way left to go. After a quick photo op at the very popular Little Red Lighthouse, I began my trek across the George Washington Bridge into New Jersey.  The GW is actually very long - 4,760 feet! I was already very tired by the time I got to the other side.  An hour later, I reached Greenbrook Nature Sanctuary, an extremely beautiful park along the coast of the Hudson.  Something that was very surprising to me was that near the end of the route you actually cross back into New York! At this point, you are very close to the end.';

let overusedWords = ["really", "very", "basically"];

let unnecessaryWords = ["extremely", "literally", "actually"];

let storyWords = story.split("");

console.log(storyWords.length);

let betterWords = storyWords.filter(function(word) {
  if (!unnecessaryWords.includes(word)) {
    return word;
  }
});

console.log(betterWords);

let totalUsed = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < betterWords.length; i++){
    if (betterWords[i] === overusedWords[0]) {
      totalUsed++;
    } else if (betterWords[i] === overusedWords[1]) {
        totalUsed++;
    } else if (betterWords[i] === overusedWords[2]) {
        totalUsed++;
    }
  }
```

1st expected outcome - the `console.log(betterWords)` statement should print out the story without the words listed in unnecessaryWords.

2nd expected outcome - the `console.log(totalUsed)` statement should print out the total number of times these words have appeared in story.

Currently I get 978 and 0 (respectively) from my console.log statements.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `let storyWords = story.split(/\s+/);` btw: these are not iterators, but you're iterating an array.

Comment: Much thanks about the split comment and apologies about the mislabeling :)

Comment: happens to the best of us, cheers!

Comment: @dandavis i would not agree. Arrays are Iterators.

Comment: @JonasW.: agree? it's not an opinion... Arrays can be, if you call `.entries();` on them: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols Before ES6 you could call them whatever you want, but _iterators_ are specific officially-defined things now.

Comment: @dandavis you can still iterate an array cause implements the iterator interface. Therefore its an Iterable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- You should split the story string on a space: `" "`, rather than an empty string to get the word count. Splitting on an empty string: `""`, will give you an array with each character, not each word.
- The array `.filter` method takes a function that should return a boolean. If that boolean is true, it keeps the item, otherwise it removes it. So your filter is returning the word if it's an unnecessary word, but that's truthy, so you'll actually only be keeping the unnecessary ones. It's probably best just to return the result of the `.includes` call directly.
- Finally, your `for` loop to count the overused words should work perfectly, but you can also use the array `.reduce` method, since it's basically a perfect fit for that use case.

```js
let story = 'Last weekend, I took literally the most beautiful bike ride of my life. The route is called "The 9W to Nyack" and it actually stretches all the way from Riverside Park in Manhattan to South Nyack, New Jersey. It\'s really an adventure from beginning to end! It is a 48 mile loop and it basically took me an entire day. I stopped at Riverbank State Park to take some extremely artsy photos. It was a short stop, though, because I had a really long way left to go. After a quick photo op at the very popular Little Red Lighthouse, I began my trek across the George Washington Bridge into New Jersey.  The GW is actually very long - 4,760 feet! I was already very tired by the time I got to the other side.  An hour later, I reached Greenbrook Nature Sanctuary, an extremely beautiful park along the coast of the Hudson.  Something that was very surprising to me was that near the end of the route you actually cross back into New York! At this point, you are very close to the end.';

let overusedWords = ["really", "very", "basically"];
let unnecessaryWords = ["extremely", "literally", "actually"];

// First, empty string split will separate the story into each individual character,
// when you want to get each word. To do that, split on a space character:
let storyWords = story.split(" ");
console.log("Story word count:", storyWords.length);

// In ES6, you can use an arrow function which is more concise. Also, the filter method
// should return a boolean. Your filter returns either the word itself (truthy) or
// undefined (falsey), and filter keeps the items we return true for, so your filter was
// actually keeping ONLY the unnecessaryWords.
let betterWords = storyWords.filter(word => !unnecessaryWords.includes(word));
console.log("A better story word count:", betterWords.length);
console.log("A better story:\n\n", betterWords.join(" "));

// For total used, this is the perfect place for a reduce:
let totalUsed = betterWords.reduce((count, word) => {
    if (overusedWords.includes(word)) count++;
    return count;
}, 0);

console.log("Total used:", totalUsed);
```

Comment: Thank you for all the great info.  I modified my code and I now get the expected outcomes.  I'll take another look at the MDN page as well to gain a deeper understanding of iterators.  I had not thought of the `.reduce` either.  Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple things going one here. The `split` as others have pointed out isn't what you need.

I would suggest something like:

```
let storyWords = story.split(/\W+/);
```

This splits on non-word characters solves the punctuation problem as well as the spaces. This will help cases where splitting on space might give you a stop word including punctuation like 'really.' if it's at the end of the sentence. It's not perfect — for example contractions will get split. If you want to improve it, look into advice for tokenizing; it can be difficult to do correctly for all cases.

Also, `filter()` takes a boolean and `includes()` returns a boolean, so you can simplify your filter statement with something like:

```
let betterWords = storyWords.filter(word => !unnecessaryWords.includes(word));
```

And you might as well use includes in you counting loop at the end too, which will be more flexible if you add more stop words:

```
for (let i = 0; i < betterWords.length; i++){
  if (overusedWords.includes(betterWords[i])) {
    totalUsed++;
  }
}
```

This can also be simplified with `reduce()`:

```
let totalUsed = betterWords.reduce((a, c) => overusedWords.includes(c) ? a + 1 : a, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I implemented some of the changes you suggested and my code is now working properly!  Thanks for the tip on `(/\W+/)` as well, that will come in very handy!

Answer (score 0):

It may be a detail, but with a quick look I can see that your split is currently getting each caracters.
You might want to do something like that:

```
let str = "How are you doing today?";
let res = str.split(" ");
```

Which gives this array:

```
[How,are,you,doing,today?]
```

That's a start I guess :P

Comment: Thank you for the comment!  That brings my `console.log(betterWords);` to 185 but my `console.log(totalUsed);` is still at 0 :(

Answer (score 0):

Convert the array of the words you want to remove/count to a regular expression of word boundary delimited list of words.

1. Use [String#replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with the expression to remove the words.
2. Use [String#match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with the expression to get an array of removed words. The length of the array is the `totalUsed`.

```js
const story = 'Last weekend, I took literally the most beautiful bike ride of my life. The route is called "The 9W to Nyack" and it actually stretches all the way from Riverside Park in Manhattan to South Nyack, New Jersey. It\'s really an adventure from beginning to end! It is a 48 mile loop and it basically took me an entire day. I stopped at Riverbank State Park to take some extremely artsy photos. It was a short stop, though, because I had a really long way left to go. After a quick photo op at the very popular Little Red Lighthouse, I began my trek across the George Washington Bridge into New Jersey.  The GW is actually very long - 4,760 feet! I was already very tired by the time I got to the other side.  An hour later, I reached Greenbrook Nature Sanctuary, an extremely beautiful park along the coast of the Hudson.  Something that was very surprising to me was that near the end of the route you actually cross back into New York! At this point, you are very close to the end.';

const unnecessaryWords = ["extremely", "literally", "actually"];
const unRegExp = new RegExp(`\\b${unnecessaryWords.join('|')}\\b`, 'gi');
const betterWords = story.replace(unRegExp, '');
console.log(betterWords);

const overusedWords = ["really", "very", "basically"];
const overRegExp = new RegExp(`\\b${overusedWords.join('|')}\\b`, 'gi');
const totalUsed = (story.match(overRegExp) || []).length;
console.log(`total overused used:`, totalUsed);
```